# Informix - Need to create date time parameters for Where clause

Tags: informix

Informix is not my normal environment and the way it handles datetime values is throwing me for a loop.  I can't imagine this is difficult, but for the life of me I'm not yet able to figure it out.

This is the SQL:

```
SELECT  agentid, 
    extension As Ext,
    resourcefirstname As FirstNm, 
    resourcelastname As LastNm,
    Min(eventdatetime) As FirstIn 
   FROM agentstatedetail AS asdr Join
    resource As r On asdr.agentid = r.resourceid
   WHERE asdr.eventdatetime BETWEEN '2016-10-20 04:00:00' AND '2016-10-21 03:59:59'
AND eventtype = 3
AND assignedteamid = 14
Group By agentid, extension, resourcefirstname, resourcelastname
Order By Min(eventdatetime)
```

Everything works as is, but the dates in the Between clause are currently entered manually- not optimal.  I just need some way to describe "yesterday at 4:00 AM" and "Today at 4:00 AM"  Will somebody please clue me in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Informix version 12.10.FC6DE, I can do this:

```
SELECT
    TODAY::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND AS today_zerohour
    , TODAY::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND  - '20:00:00'::INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND AS yesterday_dawn
    , TODAY::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND  + '04:00:00'::INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND AS today_dawn
FROM
    systables
WHERE
    tabid = 1;
```

And it returns:

```
today_zerohour      yesterday_dawn      today_dawn

2016-10-21 00:00:00 2016-10-20 04:00:00 2016-10-21 04:00:00
```

---

So, what is happening here:

- The operator `TODAY` returns the system date as a `DATE` type. The `DATE` type does not have the precision I want (it only has year, month and day), so I cast the value (cast operator is `::`) to a `DATETIME` with precision from year to second (the hour, minutes and seconds are set to zero):

  `TODAY::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND`
- In Informix, for an addition or subtraction with a `DATETIME` value to return another `DATETIME` value, I need to add or subtract an `INTERVAL` value. So I created 2 `INTERVAL` values.
- One `INTERVAL` of 20 hours to subtract from the today value (again the cast operator `::` is used, this time to cast from a string to an `INTERVAL`):

  `'20:00:00'::INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND`
- One `INTERVAL` of 4 hours to add to the today value:

  `'04:00:00'::INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND`

Comment: Thank you Luis, that did indeed do the trick.  I see the logic behind it but still don't grasp the why and how it works.  Too stuck in MS SQL apparently.  Anyway, thanks again- my head can quit hurting now.

Comment: @craigwhite I added some more information, trying to explain.

Comment: @Luis - Thank you for the explanation, it does indeed help me grasp the underlying structure a bit more.  I may have even developed a glimmer of understanding.